# Referancing an assembly from GAC to web user control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, gac, webusercontrol

I want to create web control and deploy to C:\windows\assembly\gac_msil folder (so, GAC) and use this control in .ascx files.

But these .ascx files will be under the "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES" folder (so, they will be used in Sharepoint WSS 3.0)

I want to add reference this web control assembly to these .ascx files.

Because I want to add web control to ascx file on design time.

How can I add assembly reference(from GAC) to the ascx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean using the [@Register directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1.aspx)?

Example from the article:

```
<%@ Register  tagprefix="custom" namespace="Mycompany.namespace"
     assembly="Mycompany.namespace.control, Version=1.2.3.4, 
        PublicKeyToken=12345678abcdefgh, Culture=neutral"  %>
```

Comment: Has to this assembly be in the bin folder or when iis can't find this dll in the bin folder, searchs in GAC folder? I just want to store dll file in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can do it exactly the way you described it